# SES Custom MAIL FROM subdomain verification

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, amazon-ses

I am setting up the custom MAIL FROM domain based on this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html

I have primary domain verified and I have added the MX record to the DNS settings, which I can see on the mxtoolbox.com. However, the Custom MAIL FROM domain is still in the status of "pending verification".

Does amazon check it in batch(maybe once per hour) or those changes should be visible immediately? Or is there any place where there could be misconfiguration from my side, when I see the MX record visible? What can I do to successfully configure the Custom MAIL FROM domain?

Dig command has been verified with the MX record to the amazonses.

Spf record allow specifically designed ip's, without the -all option. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Did you also add the TXT record?

Comment: The TXT record had to be added while verifying the primary domain, or if You mean the SPF, no I didn't. I have DKIM verification, so SPF checks dont need to pass

Comment: Have you done a DIG lookup to validate what Amazon sees?

Comment: Ok, I see what can be the possibility. When I run the dig -t MX [MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN] i don't see any answer.(however running it on the configured one, which i have already done i can see the answer with the MX record of the SES). So the problem is with the configuration of the DNS? And why am I able to see on network tools such as mxtoolbox.com the value of the MX record and on the dig command i am not?

Comment: Did you have a cached record?

Comment: Wait, i have checked it wrong. I see it in the ANSWER section pointing into feedback-smtp.REGION.amazonses.com. So everything looks good to me...

Comment: The only thing that I see the difference, is that the SPF record, doesnt have a -all at the end, however could this be a problem in it?

Comment: Hi it should match that syntax

Comment: Well, still it is not being verified. Is there anything that I can do the possibilities of it?

Comment: How long has it been? If its been a few hours and DIG is fine then there may be an unknown problem. AWS support should have more information

Comment: It has already been a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is struggling with the same problem, this few things help:

1) Remove Your custom MAIL FROM domain from SES

2) Add it one more time

That was the steps, that support gave us which also worked.

Simple "Turn off - Turn on" and everything works :)

Answer (score 0):

Read if you're using AWS `Route 53`!

TLDR: Manually add your MX & TXT records to your subdomain, don't let AWS auto-populate it.

We used AWS's auto populate function as we were using AWS Route 53 to manage our domain. AWS added the MX and TXT record to the parent domain's hosted zone rather than the subdomain's.

I removed them the form parent's domain, added them to the subdomain and it verified instantly.